# Error while running example of the veins in the last step of the installation

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

did the installation of the veins according to the tutorial of the site (http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/) using the operating system windows 10, but in the last step, when executing the omnetpp.ini of the example of the veins the code compiles but the execution in qtnev gives the following error:
Help me please

> Cannot evaluate parameter ‘headerLength’: 
>   (omnetpp::cDoubleParlmpl)headerLength: Cannot cast from type double to
>   integer – in module (Mac1609_4)
>   RSUExampleScenario.rsu[0].nic.mac1609_4 (id=12), during network
>   initialization

Comment: Which version of Veins did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was introduced in a recent version of OMNeT++, which no longer allows implicit conversion of `double` parameters to integer values.

This issue has also been reported [on the OMNeT++ mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/vdoiosR8NB4).

As you can see, it was fixed [in this commit](https://github.com/sommer/veins/commit/493f8a3f514bd8ffd7fb5d9666a952a4446ab177). This might be included in the next Veins release. Until then, you can follow the advice given on the mailing list, and use Veins from the repository, or even just apply the single related patch on the sources you have.

Comment: I understand now, I will make the exchange, thank you very much for the help, I could not even know what to do. Thank you

Comment: You can use cherry pick as "git cherry-pick  493f8a3f514bd8ffd7fb5d9666a952a4446ab177"