# Error in Veins tutorial simulation

Tags: casting, ide, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am starting to use `Omnet++` with veins for `VANET` simulations, but at the end of the tutorial (http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/), where it says to go into the IDE and click "Run As > OMNeT++ simulation",

an error occured :

> Cannot evaluate parameter 'headerLength': (omnetpp::cDoubleParImpl)headerLength: Cannot cast from type double to integer - in module (Mac1609_4) RSUEXAMPLESCENARIO.rsu[0].nic.mac1609_4 (id=12), during network initialization.

Ok, it crash trying to cast int from double, but i don't know where and i can't fix that!

Thanks for answers

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Please post a [mcve] consisting of the code inside the question.

Comment: You are using the wrong version of OMNeT++. Check the tutorial for a list of supported versions.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered here : [Error while running example of the veins in the last step of the installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967052/error-while-running-example-of-the-veins-in-the-last-step-of-the-installation?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

It was fixed [in this commit](https://github.com/sommer/veins/commit/493f8a3f514bd8ffd7fb5d9666a952a4446ab177). You can downgrade omnet++ as @Christoph Sommer suggested or you can try this workaround if you wanna stick to the last version.
It should work since I had the same exact problem (using a recent version of omnet++).

Best regards.