# Veins 4.7 Omnet++ 5.3 build error in windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am new to vein and omnet++. I followed this tutorial http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/ everything works up to step 3, for some reason veins 4.7 doesn't build in omnet++ 5 (IDE) and generates the following errors.

```
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc
In file included from veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:20:
.\veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.h:137:26: error: expected identifier
  enum class StartMode { RELATIVE, ABSOLUTE, IMMEDIATE };
                         ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1434:18: note: expanded from macro 'RELATIVE'
#define RELATIVE 2
                 ^
In file included from veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:20:
.\veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.h:137:36: error: expected identifier
  enum class StartMode { RELATIVE, ABSOLUTE, IMMEDIATE };
                                   ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1433:18: note: expanded from macro 'ABSOLUTE'
#define ABSOLUTE 1
                 ^
In file included from veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:20:
.\veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.h:138:24: error: expected identifier
  enum class EndMode { RELATIVE, ABSOLUTE, REPITITION, OPEN };
                       ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1434:18: note: expanded from macro 'RELATIVE'
#define RELATIVE 2
                 ^
In file included from veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:20:
.\veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.h:138:34: error: expected identifier
  enum class EndMode { RELATIVE, ABSOLUTE, REPITITION, OPEN };
                                 ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1433:18: note: expanded from macro 'ABSOLUTE'
#define ABSOLUTE 1
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:42:28: error: expected unqualified-id
  start_mode_ = StartMode::RELATIVE;
                           ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1434:18: note: expanded from macro 'RELATIVE'
#define RELATIVE 2
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:48:28: error: expected unqualified-id
  start_mode_ = StartMode::ABSOLUTE;
                           ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1433:18: note: expanded from macro 'ABSOLUTE'
#define ABSOLUTE 1
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:54:24: error: expected unqualified-id
  end_mode_ = EndMode::RELATIVE;
                       ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1434:18: note: expanded from macro 'RELATIVE'
#define RELATIVE 2
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:60:24: error: expected unqualified-id
  end_mode_ = EndMode::ABSOLUTE;
                       ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1433:18: note: expanded from macro 'ABSOLUTE'
#define ABSOLUTE 1
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:86:19: error: expected unqualified-id
  case StartMode::RELATIVE:
                  ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1434:18: note: expanded from macro 'RELATIVE'
#define RELATIVE 2
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:88:30: error: expected unqualified-id
    start_mode_ = StartMode::ABSOLUTE;
                             ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1433:18: note: expanded from macro 'ABSOLUTE'
#define ABSOLUTE 1
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:90:19: error: expected unqualified-id
  case StartMode::ABSOLUTE:
                  ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1433:18: note: expanded from macro 'ABSOLUTE'
#define ABSOLUTE 1
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:98:17: error: expected unqualified-id
  case EndMode::RELATIVE:
                ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1434:18: note: expanded from macro 'RELATIVE'
#define RELATIVE 2
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:100:26: error: expected unqualified-id
    end_mode_ = EndMode::ABSOLUTE;
                         ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1433:18: note: expanded from macro 'ABSOLUTE'
#define ABSOLUTE 1
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:102:17: error: expected unqualified-id
  case EndMode::ABSOLUTE:
                ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1433:18: note: expanded from macro 'ABSOLUTE'
#define ABSOLUTE 1
                 ^
veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.cc:106:26: error: expected unqualified-id
    end_mode_ = EndMode::ABSOLUTE;
                         ^
C:\Users\Abu\src\omnetpp-5.3\tools\win64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wingdi.h:1433:18: note: expanded from macro 'ABSOLUTE'
#define ABSOLUTE 1
                 ^
15 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:205: ../out/clang-debug/src/veins/modules/utility/TimerManager.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Abu/src/veins-4.7/src'
make: *** [Makefile:12: all] Error 2
```

I am also using sumo_win64_0.32.0. I am not sure what causes these errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like Veins 4.7 is not compatible with Windows. Would you mind trying Veins 4.6 instead?

Comment: @ChristophSommer - Thanks for a response. Veins 4.6 builds with no errors. Thank you. :)

Comment: @ChristophSommer - But now for the last step of the tutorial I get following error mentioned in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967052/error-while-running-example-of-the-veins-in-the-last-step-of-the-installation

Comment: Yup. This version of Veins needs an older version of OMNeT++. Sorry about that!

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChristophSommer - Thank you, everything works now.

Comment: Fix merged into Veins 4.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/sommer/veins/pull/69) and a new minor revision of Veins (i.e. [Veins 4.7.1](https://github.com/sommer/veins/releases/tag/veins-4.7.1)) has been released. Please download the new version to get the fix and also some additional improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered that error as well and here is what happens:

The compiler cannot resolve the `enum class` definitions in *TimerManager.h* as there is a name ambiguity with the macros `RELATIVE` and `ABSOLUTE` within *wingdi.h*

```
enum class StartMode { RELATIVE, ABSOLUTE, IMMEDIATE };

enum class EndMode { RELATIVE, ABSOLUTE, REPITITION, OPEN };
```

Quick fix is to rename the occurrences in *TimerManager.h* and *TimerManager.cc* to something else. E.g. Replace all occurrences of `RELATIVE` with `RELATIVEINS` and `ABSOLUTE` with `ABSOLUTEVEINS` etc... (or whatever you like). Worked fine for me with 4.7 and OMNet++ 5.2.1.

Comment: An alternative to editing the code is passing `NOGDI` to the preprocessor, which prevents the conflicting defines to be executed. See https://github.com/sommer/veins/issues/68.

Answer (score 1):

A patch is required to make Veins 4.7 compile with OMNeT++ 5.3 for Windows. The cleanest way may be something like on https://pastebin.com/ymzqMpEF

```
- enum class StartMode { RELATIVE, ABSOLUTE, IMMEDIATE }
+ enum class StartMode { relative, absolute, immediate }
```

that is, renaming the all-uppercase `enum class` constants to lower case ones (something recommended by many coding styles as well).